# Is there an expression that contains factor $\frac{1}{e^x - 1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

We know that some expressions of $\zeta (s)$ contains the factor:
${\frac {1}{e^{x}-1}}$.

For example:

${\displaystyle 2\sin(\pi s)\Gamma (s)\zeta (s)=i\oint _{H}{\frac {(-x)^{s-1}}
{e^{x}-1}}\,\mathrm {d} x}$

For Riemann $\xi (s)$:

$\xi (s)={\tfrac  {1}{2}}s(s-1)\pi ^{{-s/2}}\Gamma \left({\tfrac  {1}{2}}s\right)\zeta (s)$

Is there a simple expression for it which contains the factor ${\frac {1}{e^{x}-1}}$ ?

In other words, is there a simple relation between $\xi (s)$ and the factor ${\frac {1}{e^{x}-1}}$  ?

Comment: You gave one, what do you want more ? And your title should be "an expression for $\Xi(s)$ based on the Mellin transform of $1/(e^x-1)$"

Comment: I am looking for a simpler relation. If using my expression, an expression for $\Xi$ will contain complicated factor: ${\tfrac {\pi ^{{-s/2}}\Gamma \left({\tfrac  {1}{2}}s\right) } {\sin(\pi s)\Gamma (s)}}$

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$ is simpler but it is valid only for $\Re(s)>1$. It is completely obvious that the Mellin transform of $\frac1{e^x-1}$ needs to appear to obtain something related to $\zeta(s)$ so there is nothing much simpler.

Comment: In the context of $\zeta(s)$ then ${\tfrac {\pi ^{{-s/2}}\Gamma \left({\tfrac  {1}{2}}s\right) } {\sin(\pi s)\Gamma (s)}}$ is not a complicated factor at all.

Comment: @reuns, as always, thank you for the reply !